# How to read and write csv.gz from url into python

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to download last 100 days of trade data from https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/
and then write them into a dateframe i can run numbers off and acctually get it working--- have been trying the other route of having them on the hdd but still cant get pathlib os io bucketing and stuff like that to work.

have tried this code and it looked to download just some random info of the site \

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/trade/', '20200605.csv.gz')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pandas`. The `read_csv` method will understand compressed files and produce a nice dataframe as a result.